# sizeof(int) >= 2 and sizeof(long) >= 4 : Is this always true for any implementation?

Tags: c++

B.Stroustrup says the following in section 6.2.8 of his new book (TCPL 4th edition):

> Some of the aspects of C++’s fundamental types, such as the size of an
>   int, are implementation defined (§6.1).

Later, in page 150 we have the following example:

```
int_least16_t y; // at least 2 bytes (just like int)
int_least32_t yy // at least 4 bytes (just like long)
```

My interpretation of these two comments is that the size of an `int` (or a `long`) is implementation defined, but their minimum sizes are always equal to 2 and 4 bytes, respectively. That is, `sizeof(int) >= 2` and `sizeof(long) >= 4`, for any implementation.

First off, is this correct? If so, where is this stated in the Standard?

Comment: Those comments aren't using the word "byte" the same way that the C++ Standard does.  It is unfortunate that the C++ Standard provides an unusual definition for such a common term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not always true. It's possible that `char` is a 64-bit type, in which case`sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` could both be 1.

What you are guaranteed, though, is that `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT >= 16` and `sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT >= 32`, because `int` and `long` require at least 16 and 32 bits, respectively.

Comment: `int and long require at least 16 and 32 bits, respectively` Where is this stated in the spec?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: 18.3.3, where it says the minimum ranges from the C standard apply.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried to find `minimum ranges` in N4140, without success. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: 18.3.3 [c.limits] (in the C++ standard) incorporates part of the C standard, and says "The contents are the same as the Standard C library header <limits.h>". So to see the actual wording of how this is guaranteed, you go over to the C standard, section 5.2.4.2.1, which states: `CHAR_BIT >= 8`, and the fact that `(U)INT_MIN/MAX` ranges requires at least 16 bits, and `(U)LONG_MIN/MAX` ranges require at least 32 bits.

Comment: @Cornstalks Great. Thanks a lot. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First: No, it's wrong. Since it's wrong, the standard does not say it is so... ;)

[If by bytes we refer to 8-bit units, rather than `char` sized units as the spec does, then it's true that `int_least16_t` is at least 2 bytes, as it has to be at least 16 bits, and of course 4 bytes for `int_least32_t` is also true with 8-bit bytes - but C and C++ specifications says nothing of whether a `char`, which is said to be the smallest unit and often used interchangably with byte [`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to give `1`]]

The only stipulation the standard has are:

1. `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` [to that effect at least].
2. `int` can hold at least 16 bits, and `long` can hold at least 32 bits.

All implementations that follow this are fine. A system could have `char` that is 24 bits, and sizeof(`int`) == 1 for a 24-bit `int` and `sizeof(long) == 2` for a 48-bit `long` is perfectly valid. Or one where all of the types are 32, 40, 48, 64, 80, 96 or 128 bits.

Comment: In reference to you bullet point 2, where in the standard can I find this?

Comment: It would be in section 5, probably 5.2 and a couple more levels of subsection.

Answer (score 0):

1. `char` cannot have padded bits. Thus, `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` has to span the entire space that `CHAR_BIT >= 8` is defined. If `CHAR_BIT == 16`, then `CHAR_MIN == 0` or `CHAR_MIN == 0x8000` and `CHAR_MAX == 0xFFFF` or `CHAR_MAX == 0x7FFF` for `char` is `signed` and `char` is `unsigned` respectively for 2's complement.
2. `EOF` is an int defined in `<stdio.h>` that cannot be represented by `char`. That is `if (EOF == (char)EOF)` always return `false`.
3. any standard library that requires `EOF`, mostly `<stdio.h>`, requires sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)
4. the smallest value greater than 1 is 2, so `sizeof(int) >= 2` in HOSTED ENVIRONMENT
5. `sizeof(int) == 1` in FREESTANDING ENVIRONMENT is valid. That's because `<stdio.h>` only needs to be implemented in hosted environment.

Comment: add explanation so that others can relate it